# How to properly rerender based on Firebase realtime db update

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a set of counters based on data from Firebase Realtime database.

Using the onValue function from Firebase I have tried to implement it by both using a useEffect and directly.

What have I tried:

- Directly seems to cause infinite rerenders and hence causes a RN to stop the application from eternal loops.
- if i change readFeed to be a const instead the number is not updated and only shows as 1 until i rerender the application.
- useEffect works as planned, but only refreshes the first time, and hence dosent count correctly.

The users press one of the buttons in the ButtonGrid component to add to one of the counters.

**How do I correctly update the counters (e.g. whiteCounter) and the UI based on the data from firebase?**

```
    const Tracker = ({ selectedLocation }) => {
  //TODO: Selected location now includes userID, which is confusing and bad code

  const db = getDatabase();
  const [whiteCounter, setWhiteCounter] = useState(0);
  const [greenCounter, setGreenCounter] = useState(0);
  const [blueCounter, setBlueCounter] = useState(0);
  const [yellowCounter, setYellowCounter] = useState(0);
  const [redCounter, setRedCounter] = useState(0);

  const test2 = selectedLocation.split(".app");
  const ref2 = test2[1] + "/logs";

  function readFeed() {
    onValue(ref(db, ref2), (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();

      for (let key in data ? data : []) {
        switch (data[key].type) {
          case "White":
            setWhiteCounter(whiteCounter + 1);
            break;
          case "Green":
            setGreenCounter(greenCounter + 1);

            break;
          case "Blue":
            setBlueCounter(blueCounter + 1);

            break;
          case "Yellow":
            setYellowCounter(yellowCounter + 1);

            break;
          case "Red":
            setRedCounter(redCounter + 1);

            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    readFeed();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.home}>
      <Text>Antall klart pr. farge på denne session:</Text>
      <View style={styles.imageRow}>
        <ImageBackground style={styles.imgStyle} source={images.white_dot}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}> {whiteCounter}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>

        <ImageBackground style={styles.imgStyle} source={images.green_dot}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}>{greenCounter} </Text>
        </ImageBackground>

        <ImageBackground style={styles.imgStyle} source={images.blue_dot}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}>{blueCounter}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>

        <ImageBackground style={styles.imgStyle} source={images.yellow_dot}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}>{yellowCounter}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>

        <ImageBackground style={styles.imgStyle} source={images.red_dot}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}>{redCounter}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      <ButtonGrid sessionRef={selectedLocation} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Tracker;
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect works as planned, but only refreshes the first time, and hence dosent count correctly.
to solve this just add the states in dependencies array fo useEffect  just like

```js
useEffect(() => {
    readFeed();
  }, [whiteCounter, greenCounter , blueCounter , yellowCounter ,  redCounter ]);
```